# How to update A record on Linux BIND from Windows client?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

My scenario:

Organization network runs mostly Linux machines and has Linux-based BIND server.

I need that my Windows machine, which is part of that network, with update from time to time a very specific A record - so all machines in the network will be aware about it.

*Asking the same question in different way:*

Updating DNS (Windows) server remotely from other Windows machine can be done using "dnscmd" tool.

How the same can be done for BIND (Linux) ?

Comment: Did you try dnscmd to update BIND record? It could be sending RFC-compliant update command - if that's the case, it should work regardless what the server side implementation is. Of course, it could also use MS proprietary API to update an A record.

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest an alternate solution. I'm not sure if this will apply to your scenario, but it will apply if you can answer yes to these three questions:

- Is the Windows machine part of an Active Directory domain?
- Does the A record you're interested point to the Windows machine itself?
- Does the A record only need to be resolvable inside your local network?

As part of the normal operations of an Active Directory domain, Windows maintains DNS registrations for all member PC:s (unless this has been changed from the default configuration.) A possible simple solution might for you to make a CNAME from your BIND zone pointing at the record in the Active Directory domain. This of course is also dependent on your clients being able to resolve names in your AD domain (which is critical to get right anyway, if you're running AD).

Now, if you don't have Active Directory, I'm definitely not suggesting running out and setting up an AD forest just for this purpose, but if you do, and if the solution is otherwise applicable to your scenario, you might as well use its functionality to save yourself some work.

Comment: For first - probably "yes", for two rest - both "yes"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rndc` to remotely control a Bind instance.